# How do you solve this trig/geometry question?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In a quadrilateral $ABCD$, if

$\sin\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}2\right) + \sin\left(\frac{C+D}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{C-D}2\right) = 2$

then $\sin\left(\frac A 2\right) \sin\left(\frac B 2\right) \sin\left(\frac C 2\right) \sin\left(\frac D 2\right) = $

a) $\frac 1 8 $
b) $\frac1 4$ 
c) $\frac {1}{2\sqrt2}$ 
d) $\frac 1 2$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html), $$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C+\sin D=4$$

Now for real $x,\sin x\le1$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: Thank you. Using those formulas, LHS= 1/2[sinA + sinB + sinC + sinD] = 2 ie sinA + sinB + sinC + sinD = 4. Max value of sin is 1 at 90 deg. So that means all the angles are 90, right?

Comment: @TonyK, Would you mind sharing the method of your deleted answer?

Comment: @lab: Just refer to Blue's answer! See my comment there for why I deleted it. (And you can always look at the edit history if you want to see the original.)

Answer (score 1):

For $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$ between $0$ and $\pi$, the relation
$$\sin w \;\cos x \;+\; \sin y \; \cos z \;=\; 2$$
holds if and only if each term ---and each *factor* of each term--- is itself $1$. Specifically,
$$w = y = \frac{\pi}{2} \quad\text{ and }\quad x = z = 0$$

---

Now, note that any two angles of a quadrilateral have a sum and (absolute) difference between $0$ and $2\pi$ (because the sum of *all* angles is $2\pi$); thus, they have a half-sum and half-difference between $0$ and $\pi$.

Therefore, if for $\square ABCD$ we define

$$w := \frac{A+B}{2} \quad x := \frac{|A-B|}{2} \quad y := \frac{C+D}{2} \quad z := \frac{|C-D|}{2}$$

then the above applies to $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$ and allows us to conclude that $A=B=C=D = \pi/2$, so that
$$\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}\sin\frac{D}{2} = \sin^4\frac{\pi}{4} =\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^4 = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: You have to consider the possibility that, for instance, $\sin w = \cos x = -1$, if only to rule it out. Also, you can't just assume that all the angles are less than $\pi$ $-$ again, you have to consider it, if only to rule it out. I posted an answer more or less identical to yours, but then I deleted it because all these cases meant that lab's answer was far simpler.

Comment: @TonyK: Good point. I had it in my head that the quadrilateral is convex.